# Register swf / flash object playing

Tags: jquery, flash, video-capture

Big problem here: I have some games in flash. The leaderboard show the scores, but I want to associate the video of the best played games to the relative scores. To do this I need to register on the client browser the video of the swf and then send that back to me. Assumed that I know the 2 or 3 mega video uploaded to me will take some time and patience from the user, I have to do it (off course I'll upload the video only if the score is one of the best 3).
- Is there any jquery plugin able to do this? I guess no since I haven't found them...
- Is there any possibility for the flash programmer to initialize some kind of library that will register the output of the swf?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "video of the SWF"?

Comment: Think about you playing a flash game in your browser. I need the video of the played game: everything that has been output by the swf object in its container has then to be registered in any way. Got it? Thanks for the interest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way of doing what you're asking. Assuming the games are quite simple (turn-based for example) you might be able to either:

1. Record the game state on each turn and output it as XML or JSON. The data could then be used as an input into another instance of the game and used to drive an auto-play mode.
2. Save snapshots of the game as `BitmapData` on each turn. These could be exported as JPGs and displayed in sequence to simulate a video of the game.

Either way, this is something which would need to be implemented in the game itself.